# SonarQube - Views Portfolio Plugin aka Helicopter View nemo - Combined all projects metrics

Tags: widget, view, sonarqube, portfolio, sonarqube-5.0

I'm doing a POC on getting [Helicopter view](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/?did=67) on our SonarQube instance. I'm using latest SonarQube (5.1), sonar-runner (2.4), Gradle 2.3 (build system) on a RHEL 6.6 (Santiago) machine.

Helicopter view:

Plugin in SonarQube that I'm trying is: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/

The end result I want on my SonarQube instance is, to look like this: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/ and if you click on one of the VIEW(which you can create using Views Portfolio plugin), then it should give you a COMBINED metrics/info for a given view (which can be created by a user for a given Project/Product team, projects owned by a XYZ manager, department, etc or for all applications / service projects in a given organization, office, domain etc. Whatever projects you select (manually/using regular expression/etc way) in a VIEW, will be shown as one component (thus showing a user combined metrics).

Few links that I'm trying: http://www.sonarqube.org/everythings-a-component/, http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/installation-and-usage/ and http://www.sonarqube.org/measures-at-your-service/

I'm able to get the above metrics except the **COMBINED** all projects info (that I'm getting for some widgets for ex: for Unit/IT tests/coverage, Lines of Code, Filter motion chart, Components chart, Technical Debt, Complexity, Tangle index, Duplications, etc etc) is NOT showing up for other widgets (for ex: SCM Top 10 authors, SCM commits per month for a given period, SCM Top 10 author's activity etc).

Please NOTE: For the above widgets which are not showing valid data for all the component projects which are part of the VIEW/sub-view, I can see the widgets in the project itself HAVE valid populated data. It's only not showing in the VIEW dashboard where it should show the combined data (for SCM* widgets).

I'm getting the following image for SCM* widgets in the VIEW that right now contains only 2 projects (one application and one is a service project).

[image]

As I mentioned above, I'm successfully able to see valid info related to these SCM* widgets when I go to the application and service project's individual project dashboard page in SonarQube.

Not sure why VIEWS Portfolio plugin is not able to combine SCM* widgets info to show combined info when the widgets are enabled/included in the VIEW's dashboard (which uses the project's dashboard settings/widgets as well as per SonarQube Views plugin [installation/configuration](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/installation-and-usage/) documentation).

Has anybody successfully used SCM widgets that are available in SonarQube in a VIEW (created by using *Views Portfolio* plugin)? Thanks.

Comment: Views is a commercial plugin, so please contact the commercial support at SonarSource, they will gladly help you setup your Views configuration and discuss limitations.

Comment: Sure @Mithfindel, I'll check with them and update about the fix here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCM Stats plugin (and there are other core plugins) which are not provided nor supported by SonarSource. That's why we see the metrics at project level but not at Views level. For Build Stability widget, aggregation of its metrics are not available at Views level.

Views is there to aggregate code centric metrics, not the extra metrics provided by plugins working around the code (CI, JIRA, ...)

The only thing I would like to find is, why Views plugin is using the same settings that a project dashboard is using. Views plugin either should support all the widgets (for showing combined metrics for code centric or external to code like CI, JIRA etc or any widgets --OR the VIEW created using Views Portfolio plugin MUST have their own dashboard (instead of using/inherting/depending upon what dashboard/widgets we are setting for a Project).